# How to pass parameters to a MobileFirst HTTP adapter

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to run an HTTP adapter to access a SOAP WSDL service. It has 2 fields `userid` and `password`.

I have auto generated the adapter by discover backend services. Can anyone guide me to how to pass values from adapter initially to access the service?

```
function userlogin_ep_process(params, headers){
var soapEnvNS = '';

soapEnvNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';

    var mappings = {
        roots: {
            'process': { nsPrefix: 'client', type: 'client:process' }               
        },

        types: {
            'client:process': {
                children: [
                    {'username': { nsPrefix: 'client' }},   
                    {'userpwd': { nsPrefix: 'client' }} 
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    var namespaces = 'xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/InternetMobile/AbsManagement/BPELProcessUserLogin" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" ';
    var request = buildBody(params, namespaces, mappings, soapEnvNS);
    var soapAction = 'process';
    return invokeWebService(request, headers, soapAction);
}



function buildBody(params, namespaces, mappings, soapEnvNS){
    var body =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="' + soapEnvNS + '">\n' +
        '<soap:Body>\n';

    var fixedParams = {};
    for (var paramName in params) {
        if (mappings['roots'][paramName]) { //There is mapping for this param
            var root = mappings['roots'][paramName];
            var name = paramName;
            if (root['nsPrefix'])
                name = root['nsPrefix'] + ':' + paramName;
            fixedParams[name] = handleMappings(params[paramName], root['type'], mappings['types']); 
        }
        else {
            fixedParams[paramName] = params[paramName];
        }
    }

    body = jsonToXml(fixedParams, body, namespaces);

    body += 
        '</soap:Body>\n' +
        '</soap:Envelope>\n';
    return body;
}

function handleMappings(jsonObj, type, mappings) {
    var fixedObj = {};
    var typeMap = mappings[type]['children']; //Get the object that defines the mappings for the specific type

    // loop through the types and see if there is an input param defined
    for(var i = 0; i < typeMap.length; i++) {
        var childType = typeMap[i];

        for(var key in childType) {
            if(jsonObj[key] !== null) { // input param exists
                var childName = key;
                if (childType[key]['nsPrefix'])
                    childName = childType[key]['nsPrefix'] + ':' + key;

                if (!childType[key]['type']) //Simple type element
                    fixedObj[childName] = jsonObj[key];
                else if (typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object' && jsonObj[key].length != undefined) { //Array of complex type elements
                    fixedObj[childName] = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<jsonObj[key].length; i++)
                        fixedObj[childName][i] = handleMappings(jsonObj[key][i], childType[key]['type'], mappings);
                }
                else if (typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object') //Complex type element
                    fixedObj[childName] = handleMappings(jsonObj[key], childType[key]['type'], mappings);
                else if (childType[key]['type'] == '@') //Attribute
                    fixedObj['@' + childName] = jsonObj[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return fixedObj;
}

function getAttributes(jsonObj) {
    var attrStr = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        if (attr.charAt(0) == '@') {
            var val = jsonObj[attr];
            attrStr += ' ' + attr.substring(1);
            attrStr += '="' + xmlEscape(val) + '"';
        }
    }
    return attrStr;
}

function jsonToXml(jsonObj, xmlStr, namespaces) {
    var toAppend = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        if (attr.charAt(0) != '@') {
            var val = jsonObj[attr];
            if (typeof val  === 'object'  &&  val.length != undefined) {
                for(var i=0; i<val.length; i++) {
                    toAppend += "<" + attr + getAttributes(val[i]);
                    if (namespaces != null)
                        toAppend += ' ' + namespaces;
                    toAppend += ">\n";
                    toAppend = jsonToXml(val[i], toAppend);
                    toAppend += "</" + attr + ">\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                toAppend += "<" + attr;
                if (typeof val  === 'object') {
                    toAppend += getAttributes(val);
                    if (namespaces != null)
                        toAppend += ' ' + namespaces;
                    toAppend += ">\n";
                    toAppend = jsonToXml(val, toAppend);
                }
                else {
                    toAppend += ">" + xmlEscape(val);
                }
                toAppend += "</" + attr + ">\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlStr += toAppend;
}


function invokeWebService(body, headers, soapAction){
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/soa-infra/services/Mobile/AbsManagement/userlogin_ep',
        body: {
            content : body.toString(),
            contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

    //Adding custom HTTP headers if they were provided as parameter to the procedure call
    //Always add header for SOAP action 
    headers = headers || {};
    if (soapAction != 'null')
        headers.SOAPAction = soapAction;
    input['headers'] = headers;

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function xmlEscape(obj) {
    if(typeof obj !== 'string') {
        return obj;
    }
    return obj.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
           .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
           .replace(/'/g, '&apos;')
           .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
           .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Comment: Where are these two variables supposed to go? Are you referring to Basic Auth? Can you share the WSDL? I'm assuming you want to invoke `invokeWebService `, is that right?

Comment: your adapter code looks incomplete. there should be a function definition before `soapEnvNS`;

Comment: i have a wsdl which is employee login that have userid and password.if i enter correct details it displays employee details.i m very new to this so i right click on services and discover backend services and gave the wsdl url it autogenerated the adapter content.now my task is where and how to pass the parameter to the adapter so it displays the employee details ??

Comment: can you post all the source code from the adapter, the first function definition seems to be missing.

Comment: sry copy paste error i have edited

Comment: i got the answer thank you anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass parameters from client side to the http adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368267/how-to-pass-parameters-from-client-side-to-the-http-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the adapter and pass the parameters you need to call `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` in your particular case you can use

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter: 'YOUR_ADAPTER_NAME',
    procedure: 'userlogin_ep_process',
    parameters: {
        process: {
            username: 'YOUR_USERNAME',
            userpwd: 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
        }
    }
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess: yourSuccessFunction,
    onFailure: yourFailureFunction
});
```